# Polynomial inequality in real line

Tags: functions, inequality, polynomials

Let $g (x) =x^6-x^5 +x^2-x +3, x $ takes all real values. Show that $g (x)>0$ for all $x $.

I differentiated and obtained further derivatives to understand the curvature of function. It turns out $g(x)-3$ is negative only in (0,1) .So I tried to find the minimum value of $ g(x)-3$ in (0,1). However, I haven't been able to find the minimum. 
I wonder if the approach I followed would work in this problem however, I would appreciate any better alternate method. Also is there any general approach to tackle such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x<0$ or $>1$ then $g(x) >0+0+3$ since $x^{6} >x^{5}$ adn $x^{2} >x$ in this case. Now let $0\leq x \leq 1$. Then $g(x)=(x+x^{5})(x-1)+3 \geq (x+x^{5})(-1)+3\geq (1+1)(-1)+3 >0$.

Comment: Sir,how is $(x+x^5)(-1)+3 >=(1+1)(-1)+3$ in the region [0,1]?

Comment: @Jor_El $x-1\geq -1$ and you can multiply both sides by the positive number $x+x^{2}$. Then you use the fact that $x+x^{2}\leq 1+1=2$ so when  you multiply this by $-1$ the in equality reverses and you get $(x+x^{2})(-1) \geq (2)(-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^6-x^5+x^2-x+3=x^6-x^5-x+1+x^2+2=$$
$$=(x-1)(x^5-1)+x^2+2\geq x^2+2>0.$$